# Django join sqlite

Tags: python, django, sqlite, join

Hi fellow devs i have 3 simple tables which i want to retrive in one list as single objects and i have no clue how to start it.
My models are:

```
 class Person(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname= models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Phone(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone= models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Email(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what "in one list as single objects" means. Do you want each entry in the list to have data from all three models? Can a person be in the list multiple times if they have multiple phone numbers?

Comment: i want to list persons with all the data connected to it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want three separate tables? Consider writing your model as

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

Otherwise, can you (further) clarify your question?

Comment: A person can have many phone numbers and many email addresses. The model structure in the question allows for that. The single model structure in your answer does not.

Comment: Of course. What is meant here by `single list` though?

Comment: it dont have to be in single list but i want it to be nicely accesible in html file